# How to free up the space in the screen when a Linear Layout is hidden?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to show/hide a part of the window in my Android app.

I use this code for that:

```
LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layoutToRemove);
        if (on) {
            l.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            l.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
```

Now what happens is that the `LinearLayout` is removed from the window, but the space it uses is not freed (so the rest of the UI is positioned at the original place)

Now what I want to accomplish is that the space is freed, and when the `LinearLayout` is made visible again, it takes it place again.

How should I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `View.GONE` instead of `View.INVISIBLE`

The documentation for GONE at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#GONE says

> This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for layout
>   purposes.

compared to INVISIBLE documentation at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#INVISIBLE which says

> This view is invisible, but it still takes up space for layout
>   purposes.